# Yii2 register Js set Type and remove jquery

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

i want to have script tag like this for each View

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
/****** my code
</script>
```

with
$this->registerJs(....)

i get this kind of code:

```
<script>jQuery(function ($) {
.....
});</script>
```

how to add diffrent type and how to remove jQuery..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `registerJs()` is using `$position = View::POS_READY` and this one is registering automatically jQuery asset. If you don't want this you can use:

- `registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD)` - to place JS in the head part
- `registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_BEGIN)` - to place JS in the beginning of body part
- `registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_END)` - to place JS in the end of body part

Unfortunately all these will add your script in the standard `<script>` tag without the type.

To achieve this you must add it manually either by placing the `<script...>` by yourself or by calling `\yii\helpers\Html::script($js, ['type' => 'application/ld+json'])` in your view or layout file.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in the layout. Using blocks allows me to replace this for other schema.org in other pages.

```
<?= Html::script(isset($this->blocks['schema'])
    ? $this->blocks['schema']
    : \yii\helpers\Json::encode([
        '@context' => 'https://schema.org',
        '@type' => 'WebSite',
        'name' => Yii::$app->name,
        'image' => $this->image,
        'url' => $this->url,
        'descriptions' => $this->description,
        'author' => [
            '@type' => 'Organization',
            'name' => Yii::$app->name,
            'url' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
            'telephone' => Yii::$app->params['phone'],
        ]
    ]), [
    'type' => 'application/ld+json',
]) ?>
```

- Simply use Html::script($js, $options).
- Consider the usage of Json::encode() to avoid writing JS in a PHP
  file. It's prettier for me that way, and also makes variable
  interpolation easier.
- In this example you see a lot of `$this->image|description|url`
  because I'm using https://github.com/daxslab/yii2-taggedview to extend the
  yii\web\View with more attributes in order to make automate Opengraph
  and Twitter Cards tags generation.

Comment: how do i make the script be ontop in the `<head>` tag?

Comment: When you use Html::script() it will be inserted where you echo it